# Reload a tableView from the AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, reload

I have a pretty simple question, but am still finding my way around cocoa.
I have a normal rootViewController App as created in Xcode. In the AppDelegate I have a function to update the database. When a Push-message comes in while running (didReceiveRemoteNotification:) the data is updated.

But how do I get a handle on the the RootViewController telling it to update its objects and then reload the table (which is a function)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter`, see [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In your `rootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"updateRoot" object:nil];
```

and add the following method:

```
- (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [myTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

In your `AppDelegate`'s `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateRoot" object:nil];
```

Comment: Well that was worth asking, as it is much much much simpler than anything I tried, and very useful for further functions!!! Thanks a million!